# jsoup spaces error and td classname fail

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to pick, using Jsoup, the paragraph inside the following HTML snippet:

> Blockquote

```
   <td class="team team-a ">
              MyTeam
  </td>
```

The problem is that, for some reason, Jsoup doesn't seem to pick up the "td class="team team-a "
In my opinion space problem.
I tried to format ...

```
Elements team = document.select("td[class=team team-b ]");

Elements vendegCsapat_e = document.select("td.team team-b ");
```

.. but there is no solution! :(
What could be the problem in the above code? thx

Comment: Try document.select("td[class='team team-b ']");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector is not correct. To select multiple classes, use:

```
Elements team = document.select("td.team.team-b");
```

In case you'd like to know what your original meant, `td.team team-b` would be read in English as "select a tag `team-b` which descends from a tag `td` with a class of `.team`".  `team-b` is not a valid HTML tag, so Jsoup did not select anything.